# Есть ли нативный способ присвоить список значений полям объекта в Python?

Tags: python, парсер, python-3.5

Есть класс:

```
class MyClass:
    __slots__ = ('foo', 'bar')
```

Есть объект:

```
obj = MyClass()
```

И есть желание присвоить полям объекта значения разом:

```
obj.__something__ = ('foovalue', 202)  # Распаковка из кортежа прямиком в поля объекта
```

Можно просто явно указать имена полей:

```
obj.foo, obj.bar = ('foovalue', 202)
```

Но если бы был способ распаковки значении без явного указания имён полей это бы сильно сократило количество кода.

На данный момент приходится писать так:

```
class XBGHeader:
    __slots__ = (
        'id',
        '_0',
        'block_size',
        'data_size',
        'has_block_inside',
        )
    @staticmethod
    def parse(stream):
        obj = XBGHeader()
        fmt = '=4s4I'
        fmt_size = calcsize(fmt)
        # Это место меня огорчает =(
        (
            obj.id,
            obj._0,
            obj.block_size,
            obj.data_size,
            obj.has_block_inside,
        ) = unpack(fmt, stream.read(fmt_size))
```

Можно и функцию написать:

```
def setattrs(attrs, obj, values):
    # Присваивает список значении списку полей указанного объекта
    for attr, value in zip(attrs, values):
        setattr(obj, attr, value)
```

И приходилось бы писать так:

```
setattrs(obj.__slots__, obj, unpack(fmt, stream.read(fmt_size)))
```

Но хотелось бы pythonic решения этой задачи =)
Спасибо!!!

Comment: Конкретизация версии `3.5` действительно актуальна?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

В таких случаях удобно использовать `namedtuple`:

```
from collections import namedtuple

XBGHeader = namedtuple('XBGHeader', 
                       ('id', 'us_0', 'block_size', 'data_size', 'has_block_inside')
)

obj = XBGHeader(*unpack(fmt, stream.read(fmt_size))  # распаковка в вашем случае

test_obj = XBGHeader(*(42, 0, 1024, 8192, 'foo'))
print(test_obj)  
# XBGHeader(id=42, us_0=0, block_size=1024, data_size=8192, has_block_inside='foo')
```

P.S. поля в `namedtuple` не могут начинаться с нижнего подчеркивания.

Для версий **Python 3.7** и старше можно использовать [dataclass](https://docs.python.org/3/library/dataclasses.html), который является почти альтернативой `namedtuple` с допольнительными возможностями.

```
from dataclasses import dataclass
from typing import Any

@dataclass
class XBGHeader:
    _id: int
    _0: Any
    block_size: int
    data_size: int
    has_block_inside: bool

print(XBGHeader(42, 'bar', 1024, 8192, False))
# XBGHeader(_id=42, _0='bar', block_size=1024, data_size=8192, has_block_inside=0)
```

Comment: Тем не менее, к моему большому сожалению, оба решения не подходят к моему случаю. Многие структуры считываются по частям. Например некоторые поля хранят список других структур. И тут уже всё разом запихнуть в один вызов 'unpack' не получится. А 'namedtuple' и 'dataclass' могут быть инициализированны только передав все атрибуты разом.
Приходилось бы пользоваться временными переменными. Но это только портит чистоту кода.

Comment: @user3520223 Оба способа можно использовать со значениями по-умолчанию, возможно, это решит проблему. Сформулируйте отдельный вопрос, а то пока не очень понятно, что значит _Многие структуры считываются по частям_ и _некоторые поля хранят список других структур_.

Answer (score 1):

[Руководство по магическим методам в Питоне](https://habr.com/ru/post/186608/)

```
class XBGHeader:
    def __init__(self, slots, *args):
        self.slots = slots
        self.__dict__.update(zip(slots, args))
        return

    def __getattr__(self, attr):
        if attr in self.slots:
            return None
        else:
            raise AttributeError(attr)

slots = (
        'id',
        '_0',
        'block_size',
        'data_size',
        'has_block_inside',
        )
ob = XBGHeader(slots, 1, 2)
print(ob.id)
print(ob._0)
```

Comment: пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]